# keras 'shape_invariants ' : error from tensorflow backend

Tags: keras

For my model, below is the first layer. The input is of shape (10, 3, 480, 640)

```
model.add(TimeDistributed(
Convolution2D(16, 8, 8,subsample=(4, 4), border_mode="same", init="he_normal")))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
```

I getting this error from tensorflow backend
ValueError: The shape for while_3/Merge_2:0 is not an invariant for the loop. It enters the loop with shape (10, 3, 480, 640), but has shape (20, 1, 120, 16) after one iteration. Provide shape invariants using either the `shape_invariants` argument of tf.while_loop or set_shape() on the loop variables.